# combining rich:inplaceInput with rich:suggestionbox

Tags: jsf, richfaces

We want to pre-fill our richfaces suggestion-box with a inplace text.

Are there any recommendations on how to do this? I think, simple replacement of `h:inputText` to `rich:inplaceInput` will not work.

```
<h:inputText id="field" value="#{form.field}" required="true" /><rich:in
  <rich:suggestionbox id="suggestionBoxId" for="field" suggestionAction="#{suggestion.autocomplete}" var="result" fetchValue="#{result.zip} #{result.cityName}" minChars="3">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{result.text}" />
    </h:column>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could simply define `form.field` as whatever you want to pre-fill with in the `@PostConstruct` method of the form bean. Or even the constructor, really.